# is raising an exception an acceptable way to test for input type

Tags: python, regex, exception

Assuming I am asking the user to input a floating point number, my instinct is to use regular expressions.

```
'(\+|-)?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?$'
```

However, you could achieve the same check by throwing an exception.

```
try:
    x = float(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print "That was no valid number."
print "you entered " + str(x)
```

What are the pros and cons of throwing an exception rather than using a regular expression?

Comment: I would go with python check. What if your regex don't match a well formatted floating point number?

Comment: Well, use `try...except` would be more clear. And by the way, you still have to use `if...else` if you want to use regex. So use regex does **not** more simple than use `try...except` and maybe more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The advantages of letting Python check the value, and handling a ValueError are many. You have a clear intent. You can tell immediately what it should do in each case, and why. You are using the language rather than trying to do the logic all on your own through regex.

The regex approach is not as easy to read or understand, and may introduce bugs if not done right. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Python is designed to efficiently handle exceptions as a natural control structure, so checking for ValueError like that is good. By contrast, exceptions are expensive in c++ because they fulfill a different but very important design function in resource management, so using exceptions as a normal part of your logic would not be a great idea in a c++ program.

Comment: I think you’re overstating how expensive exceptions in C++ are compared to Python (to wit, I very much doubt that Python exceptions are cheaper than C++ exceptions — their *relative cost* is lower since Python control structures are all slower) but the answer is otherwise spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

Pro: you are testing if Python can actually interpret the entered value as a float.

You should put `else:` before the last print, to only print the value of `x` if the user entered a float and x is defined (i.e. if no ValueError was raised):

```
try:
    x = float(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print "That was no valid number."
else:
    print "you entered " + str(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular experession to determine, whether the string contains a float value is more sophisticated way of ensuring type. Moreover, even if string is not a valid float string, then it'll return silently.

eg. re.match('(+|-)?([0-9]+.?[0-9]*|.[0-9]+)(eE?[0-9]+)?$', "abc") will return None rather than raising error.

But the same applied to float, (eg. float("abc")) will raise exception in the program.

Thus, for most cases, one must use regular expression for building robust validation code.

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down on how you want to handle the error. Just to be clear, your code won't work the way you think it does.

If you enter a `str` to the input of `float()`, `x` no longer becomes assigned. So when the following is being executed: `print "you entered " + str(x)` you'll get: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

So, it comes down how you want to handle the error, the way you have your code written now, regex might be better.